# How to use uWS in Client Side(Browser)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

In one of my project, I have to use uWS(micro WebSockets), I don't have much knowledge over websockets, I have used websocket a litte previously, I didn't understand the uWS documentation quite well and couldn't find enough examples as per my need in internet. In this situation, how should i move ahead?

In the user manual of uWS, there is mentioned that uWS follows websocket protocol strictly so i have done:

`let uws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/');`

but unable to establish a connection, what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you're having trouble establising the connection on the client side:**

Depending on the server-side implementation, various things might be expected from the client (i.e., the server expects you to send a message with credentials, etc.). You can try adding handlers for the `onopen`, `onclose`, etc. events to get more info out. E.g.:

```js
uws.onopen = (event) => { ... }
uws.onmessage = (event) => { ... }
uws.onclose = (event) => { ... }
```

Check the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) on websockets for a pure approach. A client side library I found useful in dealing with websocket clients in the browser is [sockette](https://github.com/lukeed/sockette).